# "None" in Python

Tags: python, function

So, I have this pretty simple function (I'm a novice still).

And it goes like:

```
def add_num(x,y,z=None):
    if z == None:
        return x+y
    else:
        return x+y+z

print(add_num(1,2))
print(add_num(1,2,3))
```

So my question is, when I notice that if there is no third variable, then it is accepted. So does "None" mean basically mean that it is ok to have no value attached to a variable if "variable=None."  Just confirming!  Thanks!

Comment: what you mean by "is it ok to have no value attached to a variable"?

Comment: `None` is an object of the type `NoneType`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html

Comment: someone answered about the use of `is None`instead of `== None`. That is common but not imperative. It is just that `is` will check object identities while equals will be True in case of the same identity but also for object copies. But as `None` is a singleton you can't have a copy, it willl always be the same object if True.

Answer (score 5):

> So does "None" mean basically mean that it is ok to have no value attached to a variable if "variable=None." Just confirming! Thanks!

No.  When you define a function like this:

```
def add_num(x,y,z=None):
```

`x` and `y` are "positional" arguments, and they are required, while `z` is a *keyword* argument.  Keyword arguments have default values that will be used if you don't provide one when you call the function.  Instead of None, you could just as easily have written:

```
def add_num(x,y,z=0):
```

Or:

```
def add_num(x,y,z=5):
```

Etc. In either case, you are setting a default value for `z` if it is not provided in the function call.

Note that if you have multiple keyword arguments, like this:

```
def do_something(x, y, size='medium', name=None):
```

That you can provide them with values as positional arguments, in which case the arguments need to be in the matching order:

```
do_something(1,2, 'large', 'alice')
```

But you can also specify keyword arguments in an arbitrary order by providing their name in the function call, like this:

```
do_something(1, 2, name='alice', size='large)
```

And you don't need to provide values if you are happy with the default:

```
do_something(1, 2, name='alice')
```

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for the edits, but if you're going to edit that extensively maybe just post a new answer. Or just ping me in the comments...

Comment: All right, commenting. Default parameter values and keyword arguments are completely distinct things that just happen to have very similar syntax. Default parameter values don't stop a parameter from being provided positionally, and the absence of a default doesn't stop a parameter from being provided by keyword argument. The actual syntax for a parameter that must be provided by keyword looks completely different. [Demo here.](https://ideone.com/7j9qOr)

Comment: You can also see in the language reference docs for [function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) and [calls](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) that they never mix up defaults and keyword arguments - `=` always represents a default value in a definition, and a keyword argument in a call.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def add_num(x,y,z='spatula'):
    if z == 'spatula':
        return x+y
    else:
        return x+y+z

print(add_num(1,2))
print(add_num(1,2,3))
```

`None` is common to use here, but it's not intrinsic to default arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I ought to take a look at the python tutorial. Especially [Default Argument Values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)

This chapter explains how to define a function with default arguments.

The next is about Keyword arguments: Functions can also be called using keyword arguments of the form kwarg=value.

There are two kinds of argument:

**keyword argument:** an argument preceded by an identifier (e.g. name=) in a function call or passed as a value in a dictionary preceded by **. For example, 3 and 5 are both keyword arguments in the following calls to complex():

```
complex(real=3, imag=5)
complex(**{'real': 3, 'imag': 5})
```

**positional argument:** an argument that is not a keyword argument. Positional arguments can appear at the beginning of an argument list and/or be passed as elements of an iterable preceded by *. For example, 3 and 5 are both positional arguments in the following calls:

```
complex(3, 5)
complex(*(3, 5))
```

Arguments are assigned to the named local variables in a function body.

Comment: Did you mean to say that *he* needs to look at the Python tuturial?